# Can you list an exception to tidyselect `everything()`

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyselect

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% as_tibble() %>% select(everything())

#> # A tibble: 150 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

Say I want to select everything in the `iris` data frame except `Species`. How do I list this one exception while utilizing `tidyselect::everything()`?

My actual pipe is below, and when

```
... %>% 
group_by(`ID`) %>% 
fill(everything, .direction = "updown") %>% 
... %>%
```

and I get the following error:

> Error: Column `ID` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't just do `iris %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-Species)`?

Comment: Also, you might need to `ungroup()` before you run your `select` command, if you're trying to remove a grouping variable.

Comment: @Mako212 I had to recreate the question to show my intent. Thanks for these clues. Other question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542413/unable-to-use-tidyselect-everything-in-combination-with-group-by-and-fi

Answer (score 6):

You would do

```r
iris %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-Species)
```

but assuming you have good reason not to want that, here's a way using `everything()`

```
iris %>% as_tibble() %>% select(setdiff(everything(), one_of("Species")))
#> # A tibble: 150 x 4
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

(or just `iris %>% as_tibble() %>% select(setdiff(everything(), 5))` if it's acceptable)

Comment: would `pivot_longer(cols = setdiff(everything(), one_of("Species")), names_to = "metric")` be a case worthy of using `setdiff`?

in either case thanks for the suggestion, it works like a charm :)

Comment: Doesn't `%>% pivot_longer(cols = -Species, names_to = "metric")` work ?