# Unable to use tidyselect `everything()` in combination with `group_by()` and `fill()`

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyselect

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
             x2 = c(NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, 5),
             x3 = c(3, 6, 5, 9, 1, 9))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   x1       x2    x3
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A        NA     3
#> 2 A         8    NA
#> 3 A        NA     5
#> 4 B        NA     9
#> 5 B        NA     1
#> 6 B         5     9
```

I have groups 'A' and 'B' shown in column `x1`. I need the 'NA' values in columns `x2` and `x3` to populate *only* from values within the same group, in the `updown` direction. That's simple enough, here's the code:

```
df %>% group_by(x1) %>% fill(c(x2, x3), .direction = "updown")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   x1       x2    x3
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A         8     3
#> 2 A         8     5
#> 3 A         8     5
#> 4 B         5     9
#> 5 B         5     1
#> 6 B         5     9
```

My real-life issue is that my data frame doesn't contain just columns `x1` through `x3`. It's more like `x1` through `x100`. And the column names are very random, in no logical order. To save myself the trouble of typing all ~100 columns in I tried the tidyselect `everything()` argument shown below. But that yields an understandable error. I don't know how to work around it.

```
df %>% group_by(x1) %>% fill(everything(), .direction = "updown")
#> Error: Column `x1` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable
```

[I asked a related question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531982/can-you-list-an-exception-to-tidyselect-everything), about naming exceptions to the `everything()` argument, was too simple in my approach, and as a consequence caused confusion on the intent on what I wanted to see in a solution. The proposed solution, "*you can use `select(-variable)`*", won't work in my case outlined above (I believe). Hence, this new question. What do I do?

I should also mention that simply selecting the numerical column sequence (ie `2:100`) won't work because I need to cherry pick some columns out by name (eg `x45`, `x70`). And the order of the columns can change month to month, I have to cherry pick by column name. So using `everything()` with the option of `everything_but(column.names = c(x45, x70))` would be what I really want. Does it exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(x1) %>%
 fill(-x1, .direction = "updown")

  x1       x2    x3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         8     3
2 A         8     6
3 A         8     5
4 B         5     9
5 B         5     1
6 B         5     9
```

This behavior is documented in the documentation of `tidyr` (also look at the comment from @Gregor):

> You can supply bare variable names, select all variables between x and
>   z with x:z, exclude y with -y.

Comment: Worth explaining that `everything()` is essentially the default for `fill`, so OP's request for `fill(everything_but(x1), ...)` is simpler than they think as `fill(-x1, ...)` does that.